# Python Question about getting data from a list

Tags: python, json, validation, pipeline

My Python is not very good and I would like to see if my code makes sense or how can I improve it :)

So there is some data coming from an API, the pipeline is bringing this data to Postgres using Python. I didn't create the code but I was asked to extend it with new fields.

This is a sample JSON:

```
 "hs_lead_status": {
        "value": "Closure - Successful - Re-Employment",
        "versions": [
            {
                "value": "Closure - Successful - Re-Employment",
                "source-type": "CRM_UI",
                "source-id": "userId:10939396",
                "source-label": null,
                "updated-by-user-id": 10939396,
                "timestamp": 1632381167439,
                "selected": false
            },
            {
                "value": "(CH)_Court_Order_Filed_Advocard",
                "source-type": "CRM_UI",
                "source-id": "userId:10939396",
                "source-label": null,
                "updated-by-user-id": 10939396,
                "timestamp": 1616073472239,
                "selected": false
            },
            {
                "value": "HANDOVER_TO_ADVOCATE",
                "source-type": "CRM_UI",
                "source-id": "userId:10939396",
                "source-label": null,
                "updated-by-user-id": 10939396,
                "timestamp": 1616073465338,
                "selected": false
            },
            {
                "value": "(CH)_Court_Order_Filed_Advocard",
                "source-type": "CRM_UI",
                "source-id": "userId:10939396",
                "source-label": null,
                "updated-by-user-id": 10939396,
                "timestamp": 1616073380530,
                "selected": false
            },
            {
                "value": "HANDOVER_TO_ADVOCATE",
                "source-type": "CRM_UI",
                "source-id": "userId:10939396",
                "source-label": null,
                "updated-by-user-id": 10939396,
                "timestamp": 1616073375133,
                "selected": false
            },
            {
                "value": "(CH)_Court_Order_Filed_Advocard",
                "source-type": "CRM_UI",
                "source-id": "userId:10939396",
                "source-label": null,
                "updated-by-user-id": 10939396,
                "timestamp": 1616073225645,
                "selected": false
            },
            {
                "value": "HANDOVER_TO_ADVOCATE",
                "source-type": "CRM_UI",
                "source-id": "userId:10939396",
                "source-label": null,
                "updated-by-user-id": 10939396,
                "timestamp": 1616073219779,
                "selected": false
            },
            {
                "value": "(CH)_Court_Order_Filed_Advocard",
                "source-type": "CRM_UI",
                "source-id": "userId:10939396",
                "source-label": null,
                "updated-by-user-id": 10939396,
                "timestamp": 1609861682503,
                "selected": false
            },
            {
                "value": "HANDOVER_TO_ADVOCATE",
                "source-type": "CRM_UI",
                "source-id": "userId:12769108",
                "source-label": null,
                "updated-by-user-id": 12769108,
                "timestamp": 1608626160658,
                "selected": false
            }
        ]
    }
```

I need to get the value from "hs_lead_status" --> "Versions":["Timestamp"(only the earliest timestamp)] where the versions.value == "HANDOVER_TO_ADVOCATE"

This is the code I created I'm not sure if it makes sense or not, when I run the code in my local is not failing but I don't get a response back so

```
hs_lead_info = data['hs_lead_status']

def get_hs_lead_info(field_name):
    for field in hs_lead_info or []:
        if field['versions']['value'] == "HANDOVER_TO_ADVOCATE":
            return field.get(((min('timestamp'))), '')
```

I'm afraid to mess it up and I try it in PROD because we don't have STAGING here, if you can give me any feedback on code will appreciate it!

This is the snippet of entire the code for more context:

```
def from_dict(cls, vid, data):
    if data is None:
        return ContactsEntity()
    else:
        
        hs_lead_info = data['hs_lead_status']
        def get_hs_lead_info(field_name):
            for field in hs_lead_info or []:
                if field['versions']['value'] == "HANDOVER_TO_ADVOCATE":
                    return field.get(((min('timestamp'))), '')

        return ContactsEntity(vid=vid,
                              produkt=data.get("properties", {})
                              .get("produkt", {}).get("value", None),
                              email=data.get("properties", {})
                              .get("email", {}).get("value", None),
                              salutation=data.get("properties", {})
                              .get("salutation", {}).get("value", None),
                              name="{} {}".format(data.get("properties", {})
                                                  .get("fd_nachname", {}).get("value", ""),
                                                  data.get("properties", {}).get("fd_vorname", {})
                                                  .get("value", "")),
                              verantwortlicher_anwalt=data.get("properties", {})
                              .get("verantwortlicher_anwalt", {}).get("value", None),
                              cc_legalinsurance=data.get("properties", {})
                              .get("cc_legalinsurance", {}).get("value", None),
                              rechtsschutzversicherer=data.get("properties", {})
                              .get("rechtsschutzversicherer", {}).get("value", None),
                              fallkategorie__c=data.get("properties", {})
                              .get("fallkategorie", {}).get("value", None),
                              cc_customer_problem=data.get("properties", {})
                              .get("cc_customer_problem", {}).get("value", None),
                              selbstbeteiligung=data.get("properties", {})
                              .get("selbstbeteiligung", {}).get("value", None),
                              fd_arbeitsbeginn=data.get("properties", {}).get("fd_arbeitsbeginn", {})
                              .get("value", None),
                              cc_empnum=data.get("properties", {})
                              .get("cc_empnum", {}).get("value", None),
                              fd_mandant_anschrift_plz=data.get("properties", {})
                              .get("fd_mandant_anschrift_plz", {}).get("value", None),
                              salesforcecontactid=data.get("properties", {})
                              .get("salesforcecontactid", {}).get("value", None),
                              hs_lead_status=data.get("properties", {})
                              .get("hs_lead_status", {}).get("value" , None),
                              hand_over_advocate_date=get_hs_lead_info("timestamp"),
                              lawcus_uuid=data.get("properties", {})
                              .get("lawcus_uuid", {}).get("value", None),
                              closure_date=data.get("properties", {})
                              .get("closure_date", {}).get("value", None),
                              local_counsel_email=data.get("properties", {})
                              .get("local_counsel_email", {}).get("value", None),
                              local_counsel_name="{} {}".format(data.get("properties", {})
                                                  .get("terminsvertreter_nachname", {}).get("value", ""),
                                                  data.get("properties", {}).get("terminsvertreter_vorname", {})
                                                  .get("value", "")),
                              compensation_amount_final=data.get("properties", {})
                              .get("abfindungssumme_final", {}).get("value", None),
                              createdate=data.get("properties", {})
                              .get("createdate", {}).get("value", None),
                              mandant_familienstand=data.get("properties", {})
                              .get("mandant_familienstand", {}).get("value", None),
                              closure_verfahrensschritt=data.get("properties", {})
                              .get("closure_verfahrensschritt", {}).get("value", None),
                              sonderkuendigungsschutz=data.get("properties", {})
                              .get("sonderkuendigungsschutz", {}).get("value", None),
                              tarifvertrag=data.get("properties", {})
                              .get("tarifvertrag", {}).get("value", None),
                              fd_betriebsrat=data.get("properties", {})
                              .get("fd_betriebsrat", {}).get("value", None),
                              closure_type=data.get("properties", {})
                              .get("closure_type", {}).get("value", None),
                              mandant_geburtsdatum=data.get("properties", {})
                              .get("mandant_geburtsdatum", {}).get("value", None),
                              fd_bruttomonatsgehalt_docs=data.get("properties", {})
                              .get("fd_bruttomonatsgehalt_docs", {}).get("value", None))
```

Thanks

Comment: In the lower code snippet, I do not see why you indented the `def` below the `hs_lead_info` assignment.  Is this needed?  Also for `for field in hs_lead_info or []:`, what are you expecting to iterate over exactly?

Comment: hi @ZaydH yeah is needed as from what I can see from the code structure, I want to iterate on  `"versions": [ {"value"}] ` and if the value is =  "HANDOVER_TO_ADVOCATE" I want to get the earliest `timestamp` for that status because it can be  "HANDOVER_TO_ADVOCATE" many times but we need the first time it came to this status to get a BI report.

Comment: I see the later snippet you added did not have the extra indent.  I submitted an edit to fix that indent in the middle text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a piece of code that you can test. (online compiler https://www.online-python.com/online_python_compiler)

Please... do not put into PROD without testing before ...

```
import json

data = """
{"hs_lead_status": {
        "value": "Closure - Successful - Re-Employment",
        "versions": [
            {
                "value": "HANDOVER_TO_ADVOCATE",
                "source-type": "CRM_UI",
                "source-id": "userId:10939396",
                "source-label": null,
                "updated-by-user-id": 10939396,
                "timestamp": 1032381167430,
                "selected": false
            },
            {
                "value": "HANDOVER_TO_ADVOCATE",
                "source-type": "CRM_UI",
                "source-id": "userId:10939396",
                "source-label": null,
                "updated-by-user-id": 10939396,
                "timestamp": 1616073472239,
                "selected": false
            }
        ]
    }
}
"""

def get_hs_lead_info(datas):
    min = 9999999999999
    for field in datas['versions'] or []:
        if field['value'] == 'HANDOVER_TO_ADVOCATE':
            if field['timestamp'] < min:
                min = field['timestamp']
    return min

info = json.loads(data) 
print(get_hs_lead_info(info['hs_lead_status']))
```

Comment: hey, @Zeppi thanks a lot for this! thanks for giving me a tool to test the code as well :) one question, there is a function min() and max() why this cannot be used is there a specific reason?

Comment: For using min max you have to prepare your data before. For example you can do like this https://gist.github.com/zeppi/8327ef64eb27d05ac5f8b693f9c8f1a6

Comment: I see thanks a lot! :) I'm very interested in learning so thanks for the explanation :D